# Why doesn't [a, b, c] == [a, b, c]

Tags: javascript

Have been bug testing for about 2 hours now only to realise that if two arrays are the same. The logical operator `==` and `===` say it isn't.

Firstly, why.
Secondly, how can I get this to be true?

Comment: because they are individual objects. (the arrays i mean)

Comment: Ohh. I see. They have the same value, but are different lists technically

Comment: Object comparison is not based on the values in the objects; it's based on the basic identity of the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSON.stringify(array1) == JSON.stringify(array2)
```

You're using logical comparisons between values, not for arrays/objects.
Alternatively you can:

```
if (array1.length == array2.length){
    for(var i = 0; i <= array1.length; i++){
        if(array1[i] != array2[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: doesn't always work. E.g. if it's arranged differently

Comment: This would fail if the members are in a different order

Comment: While technically correct, it's a terrible way to do so because 1) it's slow, 2) `array1` or `array2` may have circular dependencies, 3) order needs to e preserved/normalized.

Comment: Also not all arrays can be stringified like that

Comment: OP asked for comparison between [a,b,c] == [a,b,c] not [a,b,c] == [c,b,a] or anything related to complex datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Array is a reference data type, and can never be equal.
You can check and compare the data inside both arrays, without shell

Comment: Not really.. You can compare the same array to the same array by using a variable as reference to it.

Comment: Ok, you're right. I considered the option as in the example, without a variable

Comment: Comes in handy if you compare a reference against members of an array that contains arrays. even indexOf etc. work in that case.

Comment: Commonly used in caching / pooling / queueing